# How to find the limit of this recursion

Tags: limits-and-convergence

When analyzing an algorithm's utility, I've encountered the following recursion, where $n$ is a parameter:

$ a_k=a_{k-1}+1+(1-1/n)^{a_{k-1}}$

I am interested in the limit of $a_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $a_0$ (or, rather, does it depend on $n$?).

Comment: The question is not clear. What goes to infinity? $k$ or the parameter $n$?

Comment: Sorry, $a_0=0$ , the parameter $n$ goes to infinity, essentially I'm taking the limit of the series $b_n$ where $b_n$ is defined as $a_n$ (the $n$th element in the defined recursion) with the parameter $n$.

Comment: If $n\ge1$, then $a_k\ge a_{k-1}+1$ for all $k\ge1$ and hence $a_n\ge n$, so that the limit of $a_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $\infty$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis It is fairly clear that "limit" is the OP's way to spell "asymptotics", so, if I don't mistake, the answer is $\asymp n\log(2e-1)$...

Comment: @fedja : So, it's a spelling problem :-) I have this asymptotics only heuristically at this point. Do you have a formal proof of this?

Comment: It is still not clear. Is $n$ a parameter or the index of the sequence. First, you say that it is a parameter, and you define a sequence $(a_k)$ by recursion. The recursion formula involves $n$ as a parameter. Then you ask for the behavior of $a_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Should we read $a_k$ as $k$ goes to infinity? Is there a typo somewhere? Do you have a sequence $(a_k)$ depending on a parameter $n$? Be clear with the notations, the assumptions and the question!

Comment: @fedja : A formal, complete proof certainly seems within reach now (reducing to two certain inequalities for elementary functions of one variable, which in turn are reducible to inequalities for polynomials in one variable). However, my proof is going to be long and messy, and at this point I am unsure if it is worth the effort.

Comment: @IosifPinelis And inequalities for polynomials proved by Mathematica? :lol:? I posted the formal derivation. Sorry for the delay: had some other fish to fry yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is governed by the following instance of a very general comparison principle (so general that I wouldn't even try to formulate it in full).

*Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$ be a decreasing function. Let $a_0=0$, $a_k=a_{k-1}+f(a_{k-1})$. Let $A(0)=0$, $A'(x)=f(A(x))$. Then for all $k$, we have $|a_k-A(k)|\le f(0)$*.

Proof:

Let $k$ be the first index for which $a_k>A(k)+f(0)$ (if it exists). Then
$a_{k-1}=a_k-f(a_{k-1})\ge a_k-f(0)>A(k)$, so $a_k-a_{k-1}\le f(A(k))$ while $A(k)-A(k-1)=\int_{k-1}^k f(A(t))\,dt\ge f(A(k))$, so we must already have $a_{k-1}>A(k-1)+f(0)$, contradicting the choice of $k$.

Similarly, let $k$ be the first index for which $a_k<A(k)-f(0)$ (if it exists). Then
$A(k-1)=A(k)-\int_{k-1}^k f(A(t))\,dt\ge A(k)-f(0)>a_k$, so $A(k)-A(k-1)=\int_{k-1}^k f(A(t))\,dt\le f(a_k)$ while $a_k-a_{k-1}=f(a_{k-1})\ge f(a_k)$, so we must already have $a_{k-1}<A(k-1)-f(0)$, contradicting the choice of $k$.

Now just solve the related differential equation and use the fact that $\log(1-1/n)\asymp -1/n$ for large $n$.